# How to make a image-size selected by default in Media upload - WP v3.5

Tags: php, functions, filters, media

Bare with me. I want to have a custom image size selected by default in the Media upload popup page. In Wordpress v3.4.2 and prior, this elegant code worked fine:

```
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // get the custom image sizes
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    // if there are none, just return the built-in sizes
    if ( empty( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
        return $sizes;

    // add all the custom sizes to the built-in sizes
    foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
        // take the size ID (e.g., 'my-name'), replace hyphens with spaces,
        // and capitalise the first letter of each word
        if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
            $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
    }

    return $sizes;
}


// Which custom image size selected by default
function my_set_default_image_size () { 
     return 'custom-image-size-2';
}


function custom_image_setup () {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'custom-image-size-1', 160, 9999 ); //  columned
    add_image_size( 'custom-image-size-2', 300, 9999 ); //  medium
    add_image_size( 'custom-image-size-3', 578, 190, true ); //  cropped
    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'my_set_default_image_size' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_setup' );
```

So, `my_insert_custom_image_sizes` adds the custom images to the media page and `my_set_default_image_size` should select the `custom-image-size-2` size. This code stopped working with the Wordpress 3.5 version. Do you know how I can accomplish this in v3.5?

Comment: this does not directly answer your question but is is kind of related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936080/pre-select-images-when-opening-wordpress-3-5-media-manager

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. Your [add_filter()'s](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) second argument is a function, that will affect the current option via a return:

```
function theme_default_image_size() {
    return 'custom-image-size-2';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'theme_default_image_size' );
```

You could also look into the [pre_update_option_{$option}](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook) filter, and update the value once, so you don't need to run this filter every time (may save 0.01s, but it's still saving!) :)

or good old [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option):

```
update_option( 'image_default_size', 'custom-image-size-2' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the function to  theme's functions.php file.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}


function custom_image_setup () {

        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
        set_post_thumbnail_size(640,320);

    add_image_size( 'custom-image-size-1', 180, 9999 ); //  columned
    add_image_size( 'custom-image-size-2', 350, 9999 ); //  medium
    add_image_size( 'custom-image-size-3', 600, 250, true ); //  cropped

    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'theme_custom_image_sizes' );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'theme_default_image_size' );
}


if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); //(cropped)
}
```

Using the New Image Sizes
Within a theme's template files.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); }
```